# Invalid Property Value error in JQuery with IE not Firefox

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a .NET 1.1 web app and I am using JQuery-1.3.2.min.js
in a webpage.

I am getting a Invalid Property Value when running in IE 7.
Firefox is OK.

Problem is being able to debug this in VS2003.

How can I debug this and find what line is causing the error
please?
I put a break point on the js line where I think but
debugger does not break.

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [debugging is not disabled](https://web.archive.org/web/20210116114856/http://geekswithblogs.net/devin/archive/2005/10/31/58734.aspx) in Internet Explorer.